# Generalize the KivyMD image-list example

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/image-list/#smarttilewithstar

How do you generalize the kiymd doc image-list example so the image display logic is outside of the kv file?

This is my attempt but it displays all the images in the top row only (and also leaves the first image on the left blank). Thanks.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import SmartTile
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout

img = ["00.jpg", "03.jpg", "13.jpg", "15.jpg", "24.jpg", "28.jpg", "29.jpg", "33.jpg", "34.jpg"]

Builder.load_string('''

<MyTile@SmartTile>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

<CatScreen>:
    
    ScrollView:
        id: scroll

        MDGridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 3
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(4), dp(4)
            spacing: dp(4)

            MyTile:
''')


class CatScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def display_image(self):
        for im in img:
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(SmartTile(source = im))
        return self


class CatApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        self.cs = CatScreen()
        return self.cs.display_image()

CatApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os

from kivy.factory import Factory as F
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import SmartTile

######################################
# this part of the code is to take images from my folder
img = []
PATH = "/root/Pictures" # source folder
for i in os.listdir(PATH):
    if ".png" in i:
        img.append(PATH + "/" + i)
######################################

Builder.load_string('''

<MyTile@SmartTile>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

<CatScreen>:
    
    ScrollView:
        id: scroll

        MDGridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 3
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(4), dp(4)
            spacing: dp(4)

            MyTile:
''')


class CatScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def display_image(self):
        for im in img:
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(F.MyTile(source=im))
        return self


class CatApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        self.cs = CatScreen()
        return self.cs.display_image()

CatApp().run()
```

Comment: It works. Btw, the first image (00.jpg) displays blank but is not a blank image. The 9th image (34.jpg) appears on the 4th row instead of the 3rd which means the first blank image is appearing from somewhere.

Comment: Removing the "MyTile:" line eliminates the blank image.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this add a feature..

> row_default_height: 500

```py
# Telegram : @DIBIBl , @TDTDI ,@ruks3
#  by ruks ,muntazir
# YouTube : https://youtube.com/channel/UCUNbzQRjfAXGCKI1LY72DTA
# Instagram : https://instagram.com/_v_go?utm_medium=copy_link
# github : https://github.com/muntazir-halim
# ---------------------

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import SmartTile
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout


img = ["00.jpg", "03.jpg", "13.jpg", "15.jpg", "24.jpg", "28.jpg", "29.jpg", "33.jpg", "34.jpg"]


Builder.load_string('''

<MyTile@SmartTile>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

<CatScreen>:
    
    ScrollView:
        id: scroll

        MDGridLayout:            
            id: grid
            padding: 30, 30
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            adaptive_height: True
            row_default_height: 500
            
            cols: 3
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(4), dp(4)
            spacing: dp(4)

            
''')


class CatScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def display_image(self):
        for im in img:
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(SmartTile(source = im))
        return self


class CatApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        self.cs = CatScreen()
        return self.cs.display_image()

CatApp().run()
```